# Android Button Text Starts After Center Of Button

Tags: android, button, text, center

I have a problem with buttons in my layout. Whenever I add a button the texts starts after the center of the button.

This is what I mean:

[image]

Im using a `Relativelayout` but it dosen't matter if I use `Linear`, `relative` or `table`. 
width and height are set to wrap_content.

I'd be very thankful for any sort of help.

Comment: What are you working in ? CSS? Android? Seriously need more details

Comment: Post your xml, Hope you aren't inserting space in the android:text

Comment: Android. @Gaurav Why would i do that?

Comment: would you mind posting your xml?

Comment: Had the same problem. Shut down and re-opened my IDE and it fixed itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This android:gravity="left"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't think about that! Also this seems to be a problem only in the graphical preview of the xml file. When debugging it seems to work fine with or without gravity, pretty annoying though.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem it was problem of Eclipse GUI designer. Eclipse restart should help.